# D3 parse number from string

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to using D3.js and I am having problems converting string data into a number. I am using a CSV with one column called "Belgium" composed by numbers like these ones: 54,345 or 1,234,567.

I tried to convert them into numbers by using

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Belgium = +d.Belgium; 
}
```

but I get `NaN` as a result. I also tried using

```
d.Belgium = parseInt(d.Belgium);
```

but it takes the figures before the first comma and removes the rest of the number. For example, if one number is 1,234,562, using `parseInt()` I just get 1. If the figure is 982,381, it remains 982.

Comment: `parseInt(str.replace(/,/g, ""))`

Comment: Could also use `+str.split(",").join("")`

Answer (score 1):

Remove all `,` with `string.replace(searchvalue, newvalue)`:

`parseInt(str.replace(/,/g, ""))`

so for example:

```js
console.log(parseInt("1,234,562".replace(/,/g, "")))
```

As noted below, use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt` if your numbers may contain decimals e.g. `3.141,592` to keep the floating point number.

Comment: I think `parseFloat()` would be a better alternative in case there are floats.

Answer (score 1):

I took a bit of a different approach. I used `.split(",")` to split the value into an array at every `,`, then used `.join("")` to join each index of the array with empty spaces. Used the `+` operator for ease of use but could have been `parseFloat()` as well.

```js
let stringNumber = "1,250,234.093";
let numStringNumber = +stringNumber.split(",").join("");
console.log(numStringNumber);
console.log(typeof numStringNumber);
```